# Функция vowelCount()

Tags: javascript

Не пойму в чем проблема.

```
function getCount(str) {
    var vowelsCount = 0;
    var vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] in vowels) {
            vowelsCount++;
        }
    return vowelsCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор `in` проверяет свойство, а не наличие значения; используйте `indexOf` или `includes`.

Проще так:

```js
const getCount = str => str.trim().toLowerCase().split('').filter(s => ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'].includes(s)).length;
  
console.info(getCount('Some'), getCount('Thing'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант:

```js
function getCount1(str) {
  const re = /[aeiou]/gi; // y ???
  let match = str.match(re);
  return match ? match.length : 0; 
}

function getCount2(str) {
  const re = /[aeiou]/gi; // y ???
  return (str + 'a').match(re).length - 1; 
}


console.log(getCount1('QWErtyu'));
console.log(getCount1('zxcvbnm'));

console.log(getCount2('QWErtyu'));
console.log(getCount2('zxcvbnm'));
```

Comment: А как быть, если кол-во гласных - 0?

Comment: @wan140, Тогда `match` вернёт `null` и попытка взятия `length` окончится ошибкой.

Comment: @wan140 исправил, в двух вариантах :)

Comment: Старая молва гласит: "Не множь сущее без надобности и не используй регулярки без нужды" :)

Comment: @Other Воистину :) Но что же делать, если более простой вариант уже был дан до меня? :)

Comment: Множить сущее? :)